# Render items from an array of objects, using another array with ids: ts error and best practice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I'm doing a library project (see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392997/correct-code-flow-dispatch-actions-and-block-or-verify-in-advance-if-dispatch/74393395#74393395) for more explaination) with `react`, `redux-toolkit` and `typescript`.

I'm doing an `addToWishlist` funcionality: the user simply click on the star, the code dispatches the action which patch the database and the state is updated. There is another action to remove the book from the list.

In `<Wishlist />` component I want of course render the titles and other data of each book. So I `useAppSelector` to retrieve `wishlist` and the entire `list` of books, and with help of `filter` and `map` I would get the corresponding books, but I'm not able to render them, because it gives me a `ts` error: `index.d.ts(1373, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLUListElement>, HTMLUListElement>'`

*Important note about the structure*

`wishlist` is an array of strings, which are the ids of the books.
The entire `list` of books instead, is an array of objects: every object is a book, with title, author, id etc.

**My questions:**

1. What is going wrong here?
2. Basically, is it better to save in the `wishlist` array the ids (like I've done) and so I've to retrieve the data of books in my `<Wishlist />` component with `filter` and `map`, or is it better to save the entire book (or at least, the infos that I need), so that is more easy to have the data?
3. Which is the best practice, to render the list, in the first case, where I have to retrieve data using `filter` and `map`?

Here is the attempt:

```
const Wishlist = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const wishlist = useAppSelector(state => state.user.userInfo.wishlist);
  const list = useAppSelector(state => state.catalogue.list);

  const renderBooks = () => {
    return wishlist.map(wishId => {
      list.filter(book => {
        if (book.id === wishId) {
          return (
            <li>{book.title}</li>
          )
        }
      })
    })
  }

  
  return (
    <ul>
      {renderBooks()}
    </ul>
  )
};

export default Wishlist;
```

---

**Edited - maybe the problem is not the concatenation of methods, but something in the function calling?**

*Another more little example, with another solution, but same problem*

```
interface fakeObj {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  }
  const fakeIds = ['5', '12', '878'] // this is my 'wishlist', containing only ids
  const fakeList: fakeObj[] = [ // this is my 'list', containing objects, which were single books
    { id: '334', name: 'Tony' },
    { id: '5', name: 'Milly' },
    { id: '12', name: 'Jack' },
    { id: '7', name: 'Stew' },
    { id: '878', name: 'Mark' },
    { id: '87998', name: 'Greg' }
  ]

  const renderArray = () => {
    const arr: fakeObj[] = []; 
    fakeIds.forEach(id => {
      fakeList.filter(obj => {
        if (obj.id === id) {
          arr.push(obj)
        }
      })
    })
    return arr; // the returned array is what I want: an array continaing the objects that i need
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {/* The problem actually is here! */}
      {renderArray()} 
    </ul>
  )
```

Comment: First thing you need to understand when to use map and filter and what's the return type of each method. You want to render all the books that have ids in `wishlist`. You first need to filter out the books that contains id in wishlist using filter (that returns book if it satisfies the condition) then use map. 
`list.filter((book)=> wishlist.includes(book.id)).map((book)=> <li key={book.id}>{book.title}</li>)`
[Array Methods Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I edit my answer to make it more precise regarding the structures, but your method in my case doesn't work, and I'm not sure about the logic. I'll make also an example to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using **.filter()** or **.map()** correctly, which is what's causing the errors.

The comment above that you rejected was the correct solution to this problem.

The added edited example is even more confusing, because you're no longer trying to return renderable elements, as the return is an array of objects, which can't be rendering in a UL.

So, I'm going back to the initial example.

**Problem #1**:

You're trying to return a JSX element within the callback passed to **.filter()**. This is not how **.filter()** works. You're supposed to pass a callback to **.filter()** that will return TRUE or FALSE dependent on whether or not you want the element to be filtered in or filtered out. E.g. `listOfCounts.filter( count => count > 5);` would return a modified array of all elements in **listOfCounts** that are greater than 5.

**Problem #2**:

You're currently calling the **.map()** first, which is wrong, but then also calling the **.filter()** WITHIN the **.map()** instead of chaining the map AFTER the filter. Because right now, your **.map()** call is not even attempting to return a list of JSX elements representing the book titles you want to render. These calls are meant to be chained opposite of how you have it.
An example of how to use **.map()** that's very simple:

```
listOfNames.map(name => <div>{name}</div>);
```

A simple example combining **.map()** with **.filter()**:

```
listOfNames.filter(name => name[0] == 'J').map(name => <div>{name}</div>);
```

which filters out all names that don't start with an uppercase J.

The solution above that Mr. Rafique provided you is correct / very close to correct depending on exact implementation, so I'd suggest you combine this added info with his solution.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the problem was (also) that I tried the solution of Rafique, but the renderBooks() was still signed as mistake by TS and I cannot render the result, because, I think, I don't specify the return type in the function. Than I try to put the code directly inside the return, and this works.